# How to Create Lookup by Account Type using DimensionDynamicAccountController?

Tags: forms, axapta, lookup, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a problem.
I have in my new table two new fields

1) Name -> AccountNum, EDT--> DimensionDynamicAccount

2) Name -> AccountType, EDT--> LedgerJournalACType

class declaration

:

```
public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
{
    DimensionDynamicAccountController dimAccountController;
}
```

init (for the form):

```
public void init()
{
   super();
   dimAccountController = DimensionDynamicAccountController::construct(
   MyTable_ds,
   fieldstr(MyTable, LedgerDimension),
   fieldstr(MyTable, AccountType));
}
```

4. Override the following methods on the Segmented Entry control instance in the form design.

```
public void jumpRef()
{
    dimAccountController.jumpRef();
}

public void loadAutoCompleteData(LoadAutoCompleteDataEventArgs _e)
{
    super(_e);
    dimAccountController.loadAutoCompleteData(_e);
}

public void segmentValueChanged(SegmentValueChangedEventArgs _e)
{
    super(_e);
    dimAccountController.segmentValueChanged(_e);
}

public void loadSegments()
{ 
   super();
   dimAccountController.parmControl(this);
   dimAccountController.loadSegments();
}

public boolean validate()
{
    boolean isValid;
    isValid = super();
    isValid = dimAccountController.validate() && isValid;
    return isValid;
}
```

5. Override the following methods on the data source field that backs the Segmented Entry control.

```
public Common resolveReference(FormReferenceControl _formReferenceControl)
{
   return dimAccountController.resolveReference();
}
```

Now my problem is Lookup only works for AccountType=="Ledger" not for customer, Vendor etc...

If I have a AccountType == Vendor or similant but different to Ledger I see this [image: emptyLookup]

I would want to have same the same thing that's in the LedgerJournalTrans Form

There is a solution,

thanks all,

enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be too obvious, but I think you're missing the `lookup()` method.

See:

> `\Forms\LedgerJournalTransDaily\Designs\Design\[Tab:Tab]\[TabPage:OverViewTab]\[Grid:overviewGrid]\SegmentedEntry:LedgerJournalTrans_AccountNum\Methods\lookup`

```
public void lookup()
{
    if (!ledgerJournalEngine.accountNumLookup(ledgerJournalTrans_AccountNum,
                                                ledgerJournalTrans,
                                                ledgerJournalTrans.OffsetAccountType,
                                                ledgerJournalTrans.parmOffsetAccount(),
                                                ledgerJournalTrans_Asset))
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Thanks @Alex Kwinty, you have been very helpful! Good work!